# codeigniter profile pic upload

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, upload

I'm trying to upload the profile avatar of an user. What I'm trying to do is to upload the user pic in /assets and store the path in my table 'users' under the 'avatar' field. So, I read the online codeigniter tutorial, but I can't figure out some aspects. First of all, I have in my view the form to upload the pic:

```
 <div class="profile-img">
                        <img class = "rounded-corners" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS52y5aInsxSm31CvHOFHWujqUx_wWTS9iM6s7BAm21oEN_RiGoog" alt="profile image"/>
                        <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                        Change photo
                        <?php echo form_open_multipart('pages/do_upload');?>
                            <input type="file" name="avatar"/>
                            <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and following the codeigniter tutorial I created my controller:

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
    $config['max_size'] = 100;
    $config['max_width'] = 1024; 
    $config['max_height'] = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    $this->load->view('profie', $data);

}
```

But I can't even upload the pic in the folder... plus, I have to think of a good idea to rename the picture i'm uploading and store the path in the column's table... But I'd like to upload the picture at least to start

Profile view:

```
<div class="container emp-profile">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="profile-img">
                        <img class = "rounded-corners" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS52y5aInsxSm31CvHOFHWujqUx_wWTS9iM6s7BAm21oEN_RiGoog" alt="profile image"/>
                        <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                        Change photo
                        <?php echo form_open_multipart('pages/do_upload');?>
                            <input type="file" name="avatar"/>
                            <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="profile-head">
                                <h6>
                                Hi <?php echo($user->username) ?>
                                </h6>
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Profile Details</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Your Vehicles</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="profile-work">
                    <!-- here you can add some more info, but the database needs to be upgraded for that-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="tab-content profile-tab" id="myTabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label>Username</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <p><?php echo($user->username) ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label>Email</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <p><?php echo($user->email) ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label>Member since</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <p><?php echo($user->created_at) ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: I think you should go and re-read the codeigniter example. You have left out lots of code etc.  Plus, is your view in your controller spelt correctly? Should profie be profile?

Comment: Yes, it should, but if I can't even store the picture... ahahah
anyway, i was still looking online on how to do It... The code is not the same as in the tutorial, it's simplified for my basic purpose... I'll try and read it again, but I feel i need a model to upload the path in my table...

Comment: Well it mentions things like... is the folder writeable... It also checks if the upload is valid. I'm not sure if you seeing any errors etc besides it just not appearing in your expected folder...

Comment: No error are displayed, and the folder is writteable... This is the behavior: profile page is displayed, I click to upload the picture, I chose the picture, I press ok, the dialogue window closes, the profile page is displayed with no differences

Comment: ok, what is in your profile view. Can you add that to your question

Comment: Another thing to do is to see whats in your variables (debug) so try var_dump($data) after you assign it. What does that show you?

Comment: Added my profile view... 
I also tried to put var_dump($data) right after $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); but nothin happens... No message, nothing...

Comment: Yep you are not ever ever calling that do_upload method. Your form is submitting to your profile controller / index method.... You need to set it to profile/do_upload and hopefully you have all of this in a controller called profile. Seriously a few more reads of the codeigniter example would help you a lot.?

Comment: You mean in form_open_multipart? I saw the error when i copied the view code to paste here... My controller is called pages and the method is do_upload, so i should write pages/do_upload... Anyway, when I have a moment I re-read the tutorial and re-try everything, honestly I'm a bit fused right now... I'll get back to you, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

@TimBrownlaw
I checked again my code and everything... Now this is my view: 
    
                            Change photo
                            
                                
                                
                             
And this is my controller:

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
    $config['max_size'] = 10000;
    $config['max_width'] = 1024; 
    $config['max_height'] = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    var_dump($data);
    $this->load->view('profile', $data);

 }
```

And now I get this message:'The upload path does not appear to be valid.' But according to my computer I have permissions... Could it be a problem related to docker or lamp server? 
I think it's related to the writing permission because this code right down here keeps saying that my directory is not writable.

```
<?php if(is_writable(base_url('uploads'))){
echo 'writable';
}
 else { echo  (base_url('uploads'). ' ' ."is not writable");} ?>
```

I obviously tried chmod 777 "directory" and according to my mac I got reading and writing permission. But cant upload the damn picture. Can it be related to docker's lamp container settings?